# How do I add an Electron DMG background image?

Tags: macos, electron

I have an Electron app which is not displaying the background image in the DMG build.  My package.json (top level) contains:

```
"pack": "build --dir",
"dist": "build"
```

My "build" directory does have a valid "background.png" as well.  What else needs to be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration above is correct.  There was a bug at one point in electron-builder that caused the background to not appear if a non-default OS X install folder was configured.

Answer (score 2):

> Update for **PKG** build in **electron-builder**

**package.json**

```
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.audio.application",
    "productName": "Audio-App",
    "artifactName": "${productName}-Setup-${version}.${ext}",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2020 Audio Corp",
    "mac": {
      "category": "com.audio.application",
      "target": [
        "pkg"
      ],
      "icon": "dist",
      "identity": "identity",
      "darkModeSupport": true,
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "artifactName": "${productName}.${ext}"
    },
    "pkg": {
      "scripts": "../build/pkg-scripts",
      "installLocation": "/Applications",
      "background": {
        "file": "build/icon/background.png",
        "alignment": "bottomleft"
      },
      "allowAnywhere": true,
      "allowCurrentUserHome": true,
      "allowRootDirectory": true,
      "license": "build/license.html",
      "welcome": "build/resources/welcome.txt",
      "conclusion": "build/resources/conclusion.txt",
      "isVersionChecked": true,
      "isRelocatable": false,
      "overwriteAction": "upgrade"
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "release",
      "output": "release"
    }
    },
```

---

**folder structure of build directory** -

(which at root level of project)

[image]

---

background ( data-type : *PkgBackgroundOptions* )

**PkgBackgroundOptions**

- file ( data-type : string )
- alignment ( data-type : *BackgroundAlignment* | null )
- scaling ( data-type : *BackgroundScaling*  | null )

**BackgroundAlignment**

- "center" | "left" | "right" | "top" | "bottom" | "topleft" | "topright" | "bottomleft" | "bottomright"

**BackgroundScaling**

- "tofit" | "none" | "proportional"

Reference: [pkgOptions](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/src/options/pkgOptions.ts)